# Combine multiple rows into Single row based on specific column using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to modify available value in billable and non-billable utilization, earlier its default now the value is dynamic.

I have a Billable column value as 'Yes' and 'No'

If Value is 'Yes' then it will sum row-wise and created new columns as 'Billable Utilization'

```
Billing_utilization = df[Billing_utilization] * sum/available * 100
```

If value is 'No' then it will be sum row-wise and created new column as 'Non-Billable Utilization'.

```
Non-Billing_utilization = df[Non-Billing_utilization] * sum/ available1 * 100
```

Data:

```
| Employee Name | Java | Python | .Net | React | Billable |                                  
| Priya         | 10   |        | 5    |       | Yes      |                     
| Priya         |      | 10     |      | 5     | No       |  
| Krithi        |      | 10v    | 20   |       | No       |
```

Output

Priya is in both billable and non-billable, priya name appears in two rows. I need to merge in single row with Employee Name. So expected output should be

```
| Employee Name | Java | Python | .Net | React | Total | Billing     | Non-Billing |     
| Priya         | 10   | 10     | 5    | 5     | 30    | 8.928571429 | 8.928571429 |     
| Krithi        | 10   | 20     |      |       | 30    |             | 17.85714286 |
```

```
df['Billable Status'] = np.where ( df['Billable Status'] == 'Billable', 'Billable Utilization','Non Billable Utilization' )

df2 = (df.groupby ( ['Employee Name', 'Billable Status'])[list_column].sum ().sum ( axis=1 ).unstack ().div (available2).mul(100)).round ( 2 ))
df = df1.join ( df2 ).reset_index ()
df.index = df.index

# Round the column value
df['Total'] = df['Total'].round ( 2 )
# df= df.round(2)
```

Comment: Blank values are nan or empty string?

Comment: @Corralien NAN values

Comment: Are you sure of your output?

Comment: Yes, based on billable status column from input billable and non-billable utilization column have to create in output file. "df['Billable Status'] = np.where ( df['Billable Status'] == 'Billable', 'Billable Utilization','Non Billable Utilization' )". Earlier i have defalut value in available column 168, but now the value is static. Available 1 used for Billable utilization and available2 used for non-billable utilization.. How to do that?

Comment: How did you find `8.928571429`. I understand Billing is 0.5 and Non-Billing is 0.5 but did I missed a price variable?

Comment: Billing_utilization = df[Billing_utilization] * sum/available * 100
15/168 *100

Comment: sum of billable value for Priya is 10+5(Java+.Net) / 168(Constant value) * 100

Comment: But now constant value changed into dynamic

Comment: Kindly help me to how to modify the value(168) for billable utilization and non-billable utilization

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes ( 'number' ).columns.tolist ()

df['Total'] = df.groupby('Employee Name')[cols].transform('sum').sum(1)
df['Billing'] = df.mask(df['Billable'] == 'No')[cols].sum(1) / df['Total']
df['Non-Billing'] = df.mask(df['Billable'] == 'Yes')[cols].sum(1) / df['Total']

aggfuncs = dict(zip(cols, ['sum']*len(cols)))
aggfuncs.update({'Total': 'first', 'Billing': 'sum', 'Non-Billing': 'sum'})

out = df.pivot_table(aggfuncs, 'Employee Name', aggfunc=aggfuncs, 
                     sort=False, fill_value=0)[aggfuncs].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Employee Name  Java  Python  .Net  React  Total  Billing  Non-Billing
0         Priya    10      10     5      5     30      0.5          0.5
1        Krithi     0      10    20      0     30      0.0          1.0
```

Comment: Now you have a factor in Billing and Non-Billing column. What do you want to do know?

Comment: NameError: name 'cols' is not defined

Comment: I updated my answer with the `cols` variable.

Comment: It's sample data, but in my live data have 100 columns. how to handle it

Comment: How did you define `list_column`?

Comment: list_column = df.columns

Comment: Can you try `cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist()`?

Comment: it multiple double the total value

Comment: cols = df.select_dtypes ( 'number' ).columns.tolist ()
df['Total'] = df.groupby ('Employee Name' )[cols].transform ( 'sum' ).sum ( 1 )

Comment: If total value 30 mns it double the value as 60

Comment: Do you mean `out['Total'] = np.where(out['Total'] >= 30, out['Total'] * 2, out['Total'])`?

Comment: No , in total column

Comment: And also billable & non-billable value shown as 1 for all records